# How to add custom scripts into deb file after checkinstall

Tags: ubuntu, debian, deb

Hi I have a source code and I do the following,

```
./configure 
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Above commands creates a debian file .deb. And I Push this file to any number of machine and do "sudo dpkg -i my_program.deb" it gets installed successfully

Now After install is done successfully , I need to manually create an /etc/init.d/my_program file also a user in the installing machine.

I have written a script to do the above changes, but how can I make the dpkg to execute my install script when executing command "dudo dpkg -i my_program.deb"